# C# XML Formatting to Text displays all HTML inside the XML string

Tags: c#, html, xml

I've litterally never written anything in C# and this is my first attempt. I have everything working as far as showing the XML as Pretty Printed XML. The one problem I'm running into is that the HTML that posts after the XML is duplicating and attaching itself inside the XML. I'm really confused here.

C# Display string as XML:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filepath + filename + ".xml");
string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
string xmlOut = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlcontents).ToString();

this.statusLabel.Text = "<XMP>" + xmlOut + "<\\XMP>";
```

What is being displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dumb \ should have been /. Learn from my mistakes!!!

Change from:

```
this.statusLabel.Text = "<XMP>" + xmlOut + "<\\XMP>";
```

To:

```
this.statusLabel.Text = "<XMP>" + xmlOut + "</XMP>";
```